# HTML5 frame with text on side- not fieldset/legend

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, fieldset

I'm building a bootstrap base site, where I'm trying to create a frame with text attached along is't left side (see attached sketch-up image done in MS paint). So far to no avail.

I attempted to use fieldset and legend, and have been able to create a title on top of the fieldset in the legend, but I cannot rotate the legend to sit on the side as I want to. Furthermore, the fieldset/legend solution does not work properly in IE, as the legend keeps flying around uncontrollably.

Therefore, I will like to know if you have any ideas on how this could be achieved.

I thought about just setting them frames and the text as part of my background, but as I scale my browser window up and down, everything will look very messy.

Looking forward to hear your ideas. Thank you in advance and have a great day.

[Like to sketch-up example of what I would like my frame to looklike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn1AH.png)

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle for the same?

Comment: Try it may be it will helps you.  http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/jpsn2fp5/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/gz9xq7m9/)

```
<div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">Example text here</div>
    </div>
```

- CSS

`.outerDiv{
        height: 300px;
        width: 140px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border:2px solid green;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative
    }`

```
.innerDiv{
    color: green;
    font-size: 15px;
    left: -65px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```